# Как мне найти клетку со значением text="123" в гугл таблице с помощью Google app script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Мне необходимо: 
Найти все ячейки с текстом

```
var text = data.message.text;
```

в гугл таблице
при нахождении очередной клетки, надо отправить в телеграм значение следующей клетки в строке функцией

```
sendText(id,a[i,j+1]);
```

Например:

гугл таблица:

```
111       7       sdf       sdfsd
222       4       sdv      asdfasdf
333      11     sdfs     sdfsdfsdf
222      15     sdf       sdfsdfsdf
555      3       asdf     asdfasdfas
```

если пользователь в телеграмме вводит `222`
google app script должен отправить пользователю :

```
4
15
```

функцией `sendText(id,a[i,j+1]);`

гугл таблица может быть такая:

```
Genri    111       7       sdf       sdfsd
Ford     222       4       sdv      asdfasdf
Suzi     333      11     sdfs     sdfsdfsdf
```

на Дэльфи это выглядит так
например таблицу поместили в массив array a

```
For i:=1 to maxColomns do
  For j:=1 to maxRaws do
    if a[i,j]=text then sendText(id,a[i,j+1]);
```

но я не знаю функций в google app script(((

скрипт телеграм б

```
youtube.com - Telegram Bot Tutorial: How to connect your Telegram Bot to a Google Spreadsheet (Apps Script)

// FULL SCRIPT BELOW:
// How to connect your Telegram Bot to a Google Spreadsheet (Google Apps Script)
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKSXd...
// 
// FILL IN THE GLOBAL VARIABLES token, webAppUrl and ssId
//

var token = ""; // FILL IN YOUR OWN TOKEN
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = ""; // FILL IN YOUR GOOGLE WEB APP ADDRESS
var ssId = ""; // FILL IN THE ID OF YOUR SPREADSHEET

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppUrl;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(id,text) {
  var url = telegramUrl + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");
}

function doPost(e) {
  // this is where telegram works
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Hi " + name + ", thank you for your comment " + text;
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);

  if(/^@/.test(text)) {
    var sheetName = text.slice(1).split(" ")[0];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
    var comment = text.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    sheet.appendRow([new Date(),id,name,comment,answer]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скрипте это будет что-то типа такого:

```
var text = data.message.text;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet() 
// Или = ss.getSheets()[0] 
// Или = ss.getSheetByName("nameOfYourSheet")

var arrData = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 
sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()  
// Или = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
for(var row = 0; row<arrData.length; row++){
  for(var col = 0; col<arrData[0].length; col++){
    if(arrData[row][col] == text){
       sendText(id, arrData[row][col+1])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Сергей огромное спасибо!!!!

Comment: я вместо getDisplayValues() использовал getValue() , вот он у меня и не работал)

Comment: там оказывается обжект а там стринг

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!